# Critique: How to display competitors options alongside your own without confusion?

Tags: print-design, critique, marketing

I am designing a flyer and need to compare competitors against the product the flyer is promoting. There are three options, the product and the 2 competitors.

I will have my product in in the middle with the price beneath it with a competitor to either side.

Without having the words BEST CHOICE beneath my product, what are some good design ideas to highlight that my product vs the competitors. So far I have an idea to make my product in color and the other 2 in grayscale and also make my product option a little bit larger.

Are there better ways to accomplish my goal?

---

Edit: Here is a link to the aspect of the design in question. Drug 2 is the product I am trying to sell. Drug 1 is similar to Drug 2 but more expensive.  Hope this helps with the clarification.

[image: Drug Product]

---

We did some testing with some doctors and they were still confused about Drug 2 being the main selling point.  How can we make this more clear and simpler to see?  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What type of product are you promoting? Can you provide an example of what have you tried? What's bad about your approach? Does your product have to be in the middle?

Comment: So much of an answer here would depend on the questions @ZachSaucier has asked in addition to general target audience and demographics. I don't see how this can effectively be answered other than to post a laundry list of "how to separate content in a layout." Which makes for a poor answer altogether.

Comment: Are you aware of the legal issues of comparative advertising in your country of residence?

Comment: Added an image to the main question. Feel free to check it out when you get a chance.

Comment: At this point I think this qualifies as a "Critique" question, I edited it to reflect that. And to put the image into the question for you.

Comment: @Loong brings up an **excellent** point. In the US, when you see competitive advertising it is because a parent company owns both competitors.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, first I want to say nothing beats copy. A picture may be worth 1,000 words but you're leaving it up to each viewer to determine what those 1,000 words are. That said as this is a Graphic Design Q&A I'll focus on the Graphic Design aspects.

This is somewhat a marketing question and there's no way around that. You have to understand the product differentiation. What makes the product your promoting better than those competitors and how can you visualize that? **While color helps emphasize your product it doesn't visualize why its better.**

Let's consider a fake product -- a pair of work boots designed to prevent slipping. You're running an ad targeting construction companies and employees. If the sole (get it?) benefit of your product is the anti-slip improvements than that's what you need to visualize. Maybe a guy standing in the middle wearing the boots of course and two others falling so their feet face the "viewer." That would be one idea for visualizing the benefits.

I can't really say for your exact product because A) I don't know it, and B) I'm not going to do your job.

But just changing the colors doesn't visualize a benefit, all that does is add emphasis. If the only benefit is price than you either need to find a way to visualize that, or state it.

Comment: Added an image to the main question. Feel free to check it out when you get a chance.